# PayPal Express Checkout not working CRE loaded

Tags: php, mysql, oscommerce

CRE Loaded PCI B2B v6.4.1  It comes with Pay Pal Express Checkout now problem i am having when i use this payment method its not sending any order information and when i complete the transaction it redirects me back to the website  with no order recorded and cart remain same any idea what might be the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you contacted Loaded support?

We are tracking an issue with paypal and other payment modules enabled at the same time. Try with just paypal enabled and see if the problem persist.

Also patch 6.5.1 is coming out very soon to address this and other issues.

Answer (score 0):

May be there are should be some flag/switch/setting to switch it in production mode. Currently it could be in some testing mode.